# LXML to write raw html

Tags: python, lxml

Is there a way to do the following in lxml?

```
new_products_block_text = '''
            <product>
                <territory>US</territory>
                <cleared_for_sale>true</cleared_for_sale>
            </product>'''
product = etree.SubElement(video, "products")
product.text = new_products_block_text
```

As it currently writes this, it does:

```
<products>
            &lt;product&gt;
            &lt;territory&gt;US&lt;/territory&gt;
            &lt;cleared_for_sale&gt;true&lt;/cleared_for_sale&gt;
</products>
```

How would I write the above text to lxml without building each item individually within lxml?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if products is empty:

```
products.insert(0, etree.XML(new_products_block_text))
```

Or, to just add to products, as the last child:

```
products.append(etree.XML(new_products_block_text))
```

Comment: `product.html` raises the following error: `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'html'`

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I was still thinking about element.html in the DOM

Comment: I tried both of these and they both fail: `products = etree.SubElement(video, "products")
    products.append(etree.XML(new_products_block_text))` Any ideas?

Comment: Don't create the product subElement yourself, because your text already contains "<product>" and "</product>"